# Facebook Checkpoint, Locked Profile

Tags: facebook, sms

I have been loged out of my facebook for a while. It all started when I imported some contacts from my old Yahoo mail.

They locked my account and I now have to verify it, I tried this they send me a SMS (sometimes), but when I enter it nothing happens, if I try again I get a error.

This is the message I see:

> For security reasons your account is temporarily locked If this
>   account reflects your real name and personal information, please help
>   us verify it.

And when I press next

> Enter confirmation code A code was sent to your following number:
>   *REMOVED*
>
> Once you've received your confirmation code, please enter it below.
>   This will help confirm your account ownership.
>
> Resend code

What do I, do? I have tried Google but I found nothing that helps, I can resend the code and I tried that but it does not work.

The error I get on second try is:

> The security code you entered is incorrect or expired. Please try
>   having the code sent to you again.

If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to contact Facebook with this problem. Try [this form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=mobile_account_verification) to report an issue with SMS verification.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and got this message "Thanks for contacting Facebook. You should receive an email response shortly." I'll report back if this fixes my problem.

Comment: I did contact them, but nothing happend. I tried the SMS again for the 100th time and it worked.